# Identifying parts of a string with php

Tags: php, string

I am trying to find out when a web address in submitted to my database, but this code does not seem to be working... any ideas on why it is not working?

```
if(!stripos($myString, ".com") || !stripos($myString, "http://"))
```

I am still able to submit a comment containing a web address

Comment: you do not want to except .net, .biz, .us, .co, .ca ect sites?

Comment: any site at all. At the moment I have someone who keeps posting links to random sites on my website and I am trying to stop it

Comment: then you should take out the .com check as that will be false on any site not .com

Comment: But the http:// isn't working either

Comment: that is because stripos will return 0 if the substring you are looking  for starts at index 0, which is why the php manual says to use `===FALSE` when doing a check because just checking with `!` will give a false negative. [php manual doc for stripos](http://php.net/stripos)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5.2 or later, you're better off using filter_var, like so:

```
if(filter_var($myString, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
```

More information [on filter_var here](https://www.php.net/filter_var).

Comment: You should reference a more reputial source than w3schools, like php manual http://php.net/filter_var. http://www.w3fools.com